# Create program to retype a block of text

Tags: javascript

I found this JavaScript code that retypes a piece of text that was pasted in (in the `retypePhrases` list). But when you paste in a large amount of text, with multiple lines, regardless of adding in apostrophes and commas to each line at the front and end of the line, the code seems to break. I'm betting there's an easy change I can make to this code, that will retype text on multiple lines. I just don't know JavaScript very well and not good enough at Python to do it myself (nor did I find anything like this in Python).

How can I modify this code to:

a) keep the text and not delete it and

b) allow adding in a lot of text on multiple lines (a small program basically)

```
    // OBJECT: 'retype' controls the deletion and creation of new words
var retype = {
    // ARRAY: 'retypePhrases' contains the words that will be switched
    //        The tool replaces the word contained within the element with the ID of 'retype'
    //        It works cleaner if neighboring words have different first letters.
    //        Spaces in phrases can cause a hiccup. Best practice to keep phrases as single words.
    retypePhrases: [
        'Quick.',
        'Fun.',
        'Easy.',
        'Fast.',
        'Simple.',
        'Awesome.'
    ],
    index       : -1,
    elem        : document.getElementById('retype'),
    start       : function(){
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout( function(){
            _this.deleteLetter();
        }, 3000 ); // Delay the start of a new word by 3 seconds
    },// END retype.start()
    deleteRepeat: function(){
        this.deleteLetter();
    },// END retype.deleteRepeat()
    deleteLetter: function(){
        var newWord = this.elem.innerHTML;
        if( newWord.length > 0 ){
            newWord = newWord.substring(0, newWord.length - 1);
            var _this = this;
            setTimeout( function(){
                _this.elem.innerHTML = newWord;
                _this.deleteRepeat();
            }, 75 );
        }else{
            this.newLetter();
        }// END if( newWord.length > 0 )
    },// END retype.deleteLetter()
    newRepeat   : function(){
        this.newLetter();
    },// END retype.newRepeat()
    newLetter   : function(){
        var newWord = this.elem.innerHTML;
        if( newWord.length === 0 ){
            this.index++;
            if( this.index >= this.retypePhrases.length ){
                this.index = 0;
            }
        }// END if( newWord.length === 0 )
        var newLetters = this.retypePhrases[ this.index ];
        if( newLetters.length > newWord.length ){
            newLetters = newLetters.substring(0, ( newWord.length + 1 ) );
            var _this = this;
            // Add a slight random variation in retype time to make the letter typing seem more 'human'
            var time = Math.round( Math.random() * 100 ) + 100;
            setTimeout( function(){
                _this.elem.innerHTML = newLetters;
                _this.newLetter();
            }, time );
        }else{
            this.start();
            // Yep, this makes the retype an infinite loop
        }// END if( newLetters.length > newWord.length )
    }// END retype.newLetter()
};

retype.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a better way to do this just with printing in python:

```
import time
import sys
from random import randrange

text = "This is the introduction \n text.This is the introduction \n This is the introduction \n This is the introduction"

for c in text:
    sys.stdout.write(c)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    seconds = "0.0" + str(randrange(5, 9, 1))
    seconds = float(seconds)
    time.sleep(seconds)

print(text)
```

Adjust the speed with the 5,9 line; which is the random range of time the characters get printed.